# Kohana 3 find_all returns model instead of result set object

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I wrote in my controller a conditional filter working like this:

```
$this->_view = View::factory('crud/index')
    ->bind('collection', $collection);

$collection = ORM::factory($this->_model);
if (Request::current()->method() === Request::POST)
{
    foreach (Request::current()->post('filter') as $field => $value)
    {
        $collection->where($field, '=', $value);
    }
}
$collection->find_all();
```

And in the view I have a conditional to display a message if there are no filtered results or rows in database.

```
<?php if ( ! $collection->count()): ?>
```

This gives me an exception:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Invalid method count called in Model_Product
```

The problem is that before adding the filter, my controller action was:

```
$this->_view = View::factory('crud/index')
    ->bind('collection', $collection);

$collection = ORM::factory($this->_model)->find_all();
```

And `$collection->count()` worked just fine in the view. Why is the ORM find_all() method returning a model even if I don't post, even if the code is not entering the conditional? Just breaking `$collection = ORM::factory($this->_model)->find_all();` into `$collection = ORM::factory($this->_model);` and `$collection->find_all();` breaks the whole thing. Why is that strange behavior?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
$collection = $collection->find_all();
```

`find_all()` doesn't save the query results in the ORM object, you need to save it in a variable.